# divide a ndarray by narray element-wise

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array, division

I have this ndarray (not matrix):

```
mx = np.array([[10,25,33],[3,1,5],[50,50,52]])

[[10 25 33]
 [ 3  1  5]
 [50 50 52]]
```

and I want to get a ndarray of shares by dividing every element by the sum of the column. So the result of this operation:

```
[[10/63 25/76 33/90]
 [ 3/63  1/76  5/90]
 [50/63 50/76 52/90]]
```

I can do

```
np.true_divide(mx,mx.sum(axis=0))
```

Are ther some build-in functions to calculate shares or stuff like that?

Comment: In what way it doesn't work? I tried the code and it does exactly what you wanted in Python3.

Comment: It returns all 0. Just discovered the np.true_divide(), so it's solved.

Comment: Just use `mx / mx.sum(axis=0)`. If that does the wrong division, use `from __future__ import division` at the top of your file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to how `int` behaves in division between python2 and python3. Should you start with `float` array it would work fine. There is also `np.true_divide()` that you mention in the comment.